# Neo4j The "Full Screen" button is disabled when I used it one time and I come back to normal screen. How to solve this?

Tags: neo4j, screen

I work in the desktop version of Neo4j. I launch a graph, push Full Screen button, go to full screen, go back to normal screen, and then the Full Screen button is disabled and it doesnt work. Is this normal or is it a bug? Thanks for any response.

Comment: Could not reproduce this in Chromium 37.0.2062.120 Ubuntu 14.04. What browser version are you using? In case of IE, check if the issue persists with Chrome browser.

Comment: Also check the javascript console for any errors.